# Memory leak with PowerMock on Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, memory-leaks, jenkins, powermock

I think I'm getting memory leaks when using Jenkins to execute my unit tests. If I try to execute more than ~60 unit tests I start to get most tests failing with `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space`. Often, but not always, the stack trace seems to start in or near `org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader`, although it's not consistent. the The maven surefire plugin configuration is pretty straightforward:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <configuration>
                <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                <argLine>-XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

In Jenkins, MAVEN_OPTS is also set to `-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m`.

I saw some documents suggesting it might be related to the fact that I was using an older version of powermock, so I upgraded to 1.6.0, but I am still experiencing this error.

I can't reproduce the problem locally, it only seems to happen on the Jenkins server.

I'm not sure how to reliably resolve this: limiting the number of tests cases that execute seems to work OK, but I have 150+ test cases to execute and running batches of 50 tests at a time on the server does not seem like a very good solution. I might be able to give it a bit more memory but it seems like it already has enough, and I don't think surefire needs that much memory when it runs locally. There might be a way to play around with some of the other surefire settings, but I'm not sure which ones I'd need to adjust, or how. Has anyone else every seen this, or have a suggestion for how to resolve it?

---

This might be relevant: The development environment is IBM's RAD, and the workspace is launched with the option `-Xgcpolicy:gencon`, which as far as I can tell is specific to IBM's implementation of the JVM. Might this be the reason that the unit tests run fine when I run maven from RAD, but not from Jenkins? If so, what would be an equivalent option for the standard (Oracle) JVM, which Jenkins is using?

Comment: There is JVM option that allow collect unused classes and free permgen. Try to google for it

Comment: Re [`-Xgcpolicy:gencon` (generational collection)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1106_bailey/1106_bailey.html): [Java SE 6 HotSpot\[tm\] Virtual Machine Garbage Collection Tuning, 3. Generations](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html#generations) mentions _"Beginning with the J2SE 1.2, the virtual machine incorporated a number of different garbage collection algorithms that are combined using generational collection."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved. I never figured out where the memory leaks were, but I noticed that in the console, maven would fork for surefire but never included the arguments I passed via `<argLine>`. When I added the same arguments to the maven command as:

> mvn test -DargLine="-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xmx768m"

all the tests executed fine, with no OutOfMemory issues. So I think that the `<argLine>` element might not work correctly.

Comment: We've added this option permanently in our root pom:
`<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xmx768m</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>`